# How does PUT usually work with REST

Tags: rest

Do APIs usually require all properties of a resource to be in the body of a PUT request or are they left optional so a subset of properties are updated.

Eg.

```
resource = { "id": 1, "title": "Big Book", "desc": "...", "user_id": 2 }
```

I don't want `user_id` or `id` to be updatable so I just include `title` and `desc` in the PUT. Should I make it a requirement that all properties be included in the requests or just allow a subset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably just use a subset, and receive only the properties that you want to update:

```
PUT /book/1
```

and in the body

```
{ "title": "Big Book", "desc": "..." }
```

but you obviously also need to validate the parameters and avoid any update of the id (even if passed)!

**EDIT:**

As @thierry templier said this is a pragmatic approach, since for the REST specification you should use `PATCH` for partial updates, and `PUT` for full updates.

If you're going this way just remember to document well your APIs.

Answer (score 1):

With REST, using method `PUT` updates the full representation of the resource (i.e. all content). So if you only send a subset of properties, the missing ones should be set to null. If you want to only update a subset of properties, you should use the method `PATCH`.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry